# Adding time offsets to create future dates

Tags: ruby, datetime, url

How can I shorten this (working) code to create future dates in ruby for use as params in URLs?

I'm doing:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'time'

now=Time.new()
now_year=now.strftime('%Y').to_i
now_month=now.strftime('%m').to_i
now_day=now.strftime('%d').to_i
now_hour=now.strftime('%H').to_i

start_hour=(now_hour + 1)
end_hour=(now_hour + 2)

start_datetime=Time.new(now_year, now_month, now_day, start_hour)
end_datetime=Time.new(now_year, now_month, now_day, end_hour)

starts=CGI.escape(start_datetime.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ"))
ends=CGI.escape(end_datetime.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ"))
```

and it works, but it seems long and clumsy.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [add seconds directly to a `Time` object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#method-i-2B), so you could do:

```
now = Time.now.utc
starts = now + 3600 # Add 1 hour's worth of seconds (60 * 60)
ends   = now + 7200 # Add 2 hours
```

and then do the `strftime`-formatting.

Of course, since you need to do this twice, I'd suggest adding a method to avoid the repetition, i.e.:

```
def offset_utc_timestamp(offset, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ")
  time = Time.now.utc + offset
  time.strftime(format)
end
```

You may want to split it up differently (i.e. have the method just return a `Time` object, which you make into a string elsewhere; or have the method also do the URL escaping).

I'd also recommend using the [`URI.escape` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-escape) instead, if this is intended for URLs

With all that your code becomes:

```
starts = URI.escape(offset_utc_timestamp(3600))
ends   = URI.escape(offset_utc_timestamp(7200))
```

Alternatively, the [ActiveSupport gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) has a ton of helpful time stuff, letting you do things like `2.hours.from_now.utc`

Comment: Looks good.  btw I had tried using the URI.escape but it didn't code things correctly for me (or at all) so I switched to CGI.escape at the suggestion of a colleague

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Gotcha. I am curious, though, how these URLs should end up looking; there shouldn't really be anything that needs escaping, really. Also, you can pass a regexp or string to `URI.escape` (see docs), telling it what should be forcibly escaped. With your input, `URI.escape(string, ":")` will produce the exact same output as `CGI.escape(string)`

Comment: I should have been more specific, I need it to end up with characters like ":" as `%3A` as I am trying to just replicate what a current param is in our system.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Ah, ok. Well, it's totally up you. I'd probably end up sticking with `CGI.escape` as well, since it does what you want by default. As mentioned, you can use `URI.escape` too, if you provide the 2nd argument, but it's more work.

Answer (score 2):

Once you start storing some strings in percent-encoded form, you have the added burden of keeping track of which strings are encoded, and which strings aren't.<sup>1</sup>  Therefore, you should avoid *ad hoc* escaping.

Instead, I recommend **keeping all strings in unescaped form,** and performing the escaping at the last minute when constructing the URL.  That also forces you to use a URL-construction procedure that handles all escaping for you — the way it should be done.  For example,

```
import urllib

start = (Time.now.utc + 3600).strftime(…)
end   = (Time.now.utc + 7200).strftime(…)

query_string = urllib.urlencode({ 'start': start, 'end', end })
```

---

<sup>1</sup> One way to keep track of which variables contain encoded strings is to use [some form of Hungarian Notation](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) (see the section called *The Real Solution*).

Comment: +1 for advocating "just in time"-encoding